# ¿Se puede crear en Python una aplicación de escritorio que controle el teclado para eliminar 2 espacios seguidos en todo el ordenador?

Tags: python, aplicación-escritorio, teclado

¡Hola! El problema  es  que el  teclado funciona como quiere. Especialmente la barra de espacio. A  veces pone un sólo espacio, como tiene que ser, pero otras, o no  pone ningún espacio olo que más memolesta: pone 2 seguidos.

Me gustaría saber si se  puede  hacer una  aplicación en python que haga algo similar a lo que hace esto:

```py
import re

def normalize_whitespace(string):
    return re.sub(r'(\s)\1{1,}', r'\1', string)
```

Pero que lo haga en segundo plano y directamente según se va presionando cada tecla, detectando cualquier lugar en que  se pulse la barra de espacio, como el formulario donde estoy escribiendo ahora en el navegador, un editor de texto como Word o cualquier IDE u otra aplicación cualquiera que requiera introducir texto.

En caso de no ser posible en Python, me gustaría saber  si es posible en otro lenguaje de programación.

¡Muchas  gracias!

Comment: Comprar otro teclado sale más fácil y barato.

Comment: jajajja Bueno, barato... Éste me costó más  de 30€... Y hasta  el momento es lo único malo que le he visto... :D

Comment: Lo que buscas hacer se llama [*keylogger*](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keylogger) y usualmente se programa a bajo nivel (tal vez con lenguaje C o en Ensamblador). Pero la [sugerencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386000/se-puede-crear-en-python-una-aplicaci%c3%b3n-de-escritorio-que-controle-el-teclado-p#comment691521_386000) de @CandidMoe tal vez sea la más acertada. Saludos

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) y [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/)